# Is there a simple way to reorganize my db?

Tags: python, mongodb, csv

I am new to working with mongoDB and csv's, and I have a dataset that I am working on. I downloaded the dataset as a csv and am wondering if there is a way to reorganize the data. Currently each entry looks like this:

```json
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "65a9be67f8523e6277bf7500"
  },
  "Country": "BANGLADESH",
  "Country Code": "BGD",
  "Year": 2017,
  "Wind Electricity Produced": 0.01,
  "Hydro Electricity Produced": 1.03,
  "Solar Electricity Produced": 0.25,
  "Renewable bioenergy (TWh)": 0.03,
  "Total Percentage of Renewables": 1.9155419,
  "Population Rank": 8,
  "Population": 169828911,
  "Hydro ELECTRIC SHARE ONLY  (% electricity)": 1.4947032,
  "Hydro SHARE ALL (% equivalent primary energy)": 0.7132308,
  "Electricity CONSUMPTION From Hydro ": 1.03,
  "Wind SHARE ELECTRIC ONLY  (% electricity)": 0.014511681,
  "Wind SHARE ALL  (% equivalent primary energy)": 0.003521487,
  "Electricty Generated From Wind ": 0.01,
  "Solar ELECTRICITY ONLY (% electricity)": 0.36279202,
  "Solar SHARE ALL (% equivalent primary energy)": 0.17552204,
  "Solar Electricity Usage": 0.25,
  "City": "Dhaka",
  "Air Pollution": 80,
  "Coordinates": "23.777176, 90.399452."
},
```

I would like to reorganize it so that it looks like this:

```json
 "Country": "BANGLADESH",
    {
        "City": "Dhaka",
            {
                "_id": {
                    "$oid": "65a9be67f8523e6277bf7500"
                },
                "Country Code": "BGD",
                "Year": 2017,
                "Wind Electricity Produced": 0.01,
                "Hydro Electricity Produced": 1.03,
                "Solar Electricity Produced": 0.25,
                "Renewable bioenergy (TWh)": 0.03,
                "Total Percentage of Renewables": 1.9155419,
                "Population Rank": 8,
                "Population": 169828911,
                "Hydro ELECTRIC SHARE ONLY  (% electricity)": 1.4947032,
                "Hydro SHARE ALL (% equivalent primary energy)": 0.7132308,
                "Electricity CONSUMPTION From Hydro ": 1.03,
                "Wind SHARE ELECTRIC ONLY  (% electricity)": 0.014511681,
                "Wind SHARE ALL  (% equivalent primary energy)": 0.003521487,
                "Electricty Generated From Wind ": 0.01,
                "Solar ELECTRICITY ONLY (% electricity)": 0.36279202,
                "Solar SHARE ALL (% equivalent primary energy)": 0.17552204,
                "Solar Electricity Usage": 0.25
                "Air Pollution": 80,
                "Coordinates": "23.777176, 90.399452."
            },
        }
    }
```

This way, when converting the dataset to JSON, it can reference each country and then city to only return the data in each city.

Would it be best to use a Python `groupby` and make it a new dataset with each country and city? or is there a simpler way to do this either in mongodb or just in Python or JS?

Comment: mongodb is not a big JSON file, it uses JSON to store individual records, create an index on the fields you want to query on

Comment: Actually, the answer is yes, you can reorganize the data. The only thing is that the `_id` field is a record identifier and if you don't leave it in the top level of the object, you are asking for trouble. That said, this smells like a so-called XY problem, i.e. you're asking the wrong question. What is the actual goal that you're working on and why do you think that this format is an obstacle for you?